# Abort() has been called while i calculate a logarithm

Tags: c++

I need to calculate this function, considering a negative logarithm or logarithm of 0 and not to display these [image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a = 2;
    double b = 2;
    double x1 = -3;
    double x2 = 3;
    double y1 = -2;
    double y2 = 2;
    double xh = 0.2;
    double yh = 0.2;

    while (x1 <= x2 && y1 <= y2)
    {
        string result = "";

        if (x1 + y1 < 0)
        {
            result = to_string(pow(a, log10(fabs(x1))) + pow(b, y2));
        }
        else if(x1*y1 > 0)
        {
            if (b * x1 * y2 <= 0)
            {
                result = "Logarithm of a negative number or 0 is not possible";
            }
            else
            {
                result = to_string(a * x1 * x1 + log(b * x1 * y2));
            }
        }

        x1 += xh;
        y1 += yh;

        if (result == "Logarithm of a negative number and 0 is not possible")
        {
            cout << result << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << stof(result) << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А что надо вывести, когда `x == 3 && y == -1`? Т.е. и `x+y` не меньше нуля, и `x*y` не больше нуля? У вас условие верно поставлено? И логарифмы точно разные? один десятичный, второй натуральный? И значения функции интересуют только вдоль одной прямой, а не во всем диапазоне?

Comment: У вас для значений `x1=-0.4`, `y1=0.6` строка `result` получается пустая, и `stof` вызывает исключение. Получается, что `x1+y1<0` это `false`, и `x1*y1>0` тоже `false`. В итоге `result` остается "пустой строкой", потому что с начала итерации значение ему не поменяли.

Comment: @КоржикБогатырский Там вообще условие вызывает больше вопросов, чем ответов...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если запустить вашу программу в отладчике, то мы можем увидеть, что при вызове исключения `result=""`. Функция `stof` не может обработать пустую строку. `result` оказывается пустым, поскольку его значение не было изменено с начала итерации, ведь оба условия (`x1+y1<0` и `x1*y1>0`) оказались ложными.
Действительно, для таких аргументов `x` и `y` значение функции `z(x,y)` не определено.

После блока `else if (x1 * y1 > 0) {...}` добавьте что-то вроде:

```
else result = "Function value is undefined";
```

Тогда также замените `if (result == "Logarithm of a negative number and 0 is not possible")` на:

```
if ((result == "Logarithm of a negative number and 0 is not possible") ||
    (result == "Function value is undefined"))
```